# word/byte addressability & non-aligned/aligned access to main memory

Tags: memory, assembly, memory-management, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I have encountered two pairs of concepts in Tannebaum's MOS:

- word vs. byte addressability
- aligned vs. non-aligned access

I don't really understand how these two pairs relate. In particular: 
What would be the point of having byte addressable memory (1), with non-aligned access not allowed (2) ? It seems to me that (2) means we cannot take advantage of (1).

In other words, would:

- word-addressable memory  with non-aligned access allowed

offer to the programmer any possibilities that

- word-addressable memory  with non-aligned access not allowed

cannot?

Thank you

Comment: _"What would be the point of having byte addressable memory (1), with non-aligned access not allowed"_ Because usually you also have instructions for loading and storing bytes (e.g. `ldrb`/`strb` on ARM, `lb`/`sb` on MIPS, etc). These do not have word-alignment requirements on the effective address.

Comment: (2) might simplify for the hardware designer. That could be more important than simplifying for the programmer.

Comment: @Michael : do you mean some instructions might have word-alignment requirements while others don't?

Comment: Yes. While a "load word" instruction might have word-alignment requirements, it makes no sense for a "load byte" instruction to have that requirement.

Comment: The only reasonable natural alignment for a byte is, well, bytes. Or 1, if you prefer. In other words, a byte is always aligned.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but you might find this question and answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919961/addressable-vs-alignment/33932080#33932080

Comment: @GabrielSouthern Thanks. Indeed v. useful.

Answer (score 2):

Word addressability:

In ye olde days there were computers that operated on 12, 14, and 36 bits. These were machine words. You could not address a byte in such systems—they didn't have bytes. You addressed words.

Aligned access:

It requires multiple cycles to access unaligned data. The processor has to take extra steps to grab the data in pieces. Some processors (notably RISC) prohibit unaligned accesses entirely for performance.

Such systems are still byte addressable because you can access individual bytes for byte operands.